# How do you point to a value in an array in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

So I need to point to a specific value in the array.  I don't know how to get the address though, so for example what I need to do (in C) is this call a function like this,

```
int p = 5;
cqs(&a[0], p);
cqs(&a[p+1], n-p-1);
```

How would I point to the specific index in ARM?  I've tried

```
ldr r6, [r0, r3, asl #2]
ldr r0, =r6
bl cqs
```

but the compiler doesn't like that.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the base address in `r0`, the (variable) index in `r3`, and the size of each element is 4 bytes:

```
add r0, r0, r3, lsl#2    @ r0 += r3 * 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Address math is just integer add/subtract.

Looking at C compiler output is one way to learn asm.

```
void cqs(int *);

int arrayptr(int *a) {
  int p = 5;
  cqs(&a[p+1]);
  return 0;
}
```

[compile to (godbolt ARM gcc 4.8)](http://goo.gl/Jt0s7x)

```
arrayptr(int*):
    push    {r3, lr}    @
    adds    r0, r0, #24 @, a,
    bl  cqs(int*)   @
    movs    r0, #0  @,
    pop {r3, pc}    @
```

So `adds  dest, src, imm` looks like a good way to offset an array pointer to point farther along in the array.

The `return 0;` stops gcc from tail-call optimizing the function call into a jump.